# dynamically update text on buttons in tkinter

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I'm working on an application right now and am having some difficulty with something. I would like to have the key from the dictionary as the label and the four numbers in the list are the value to the corresponding key and show be put in the buttons. When I press a button, I want to change the label and the button so that it goes to the next element in the dictionary and keep repeating the process until there are no more elements in the dictionary.

Here is my code so far:

```
import tkinter as tk
q_a = {"label":[1,2,3,4],"label 2":[5,6,7,8]}
class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.label.pack()
        self.remaining = len(q_a)
        self.countdown(self.remaining-1)

    def loop(self, remaining=None):
        if self.remaining <= 0:
            self.label.configure(text="The end")
        else:
            self.label.configure(text=(list(q_a.keys())[self.remaining-1]))
            dictionary_index = list(q_a.keys())[self.remaining-1]
            self.remaining = self.remaining - 1
            button1 = tk.Button(self, text=q_a[dictionary_index][0],
                           command=lambda: self.loop).pack()
            button2 = tk.Button(self, text=q_a[dictionary_index][1],
                           command=lambda: self.loop).pack()
            button3 = tk.Button(self, text=q_a[dictionary_index][2],
                           command=lambda: self.loop).pack()
            button4 = tk.Button(self, text=q_a[dictionary_index][3],
                           command=lambda: self.loop).pack()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Keep data as list to keep order. Create empty label and buttons and add function which replace text on label and buttons using variable which remember last `index` on this list.

Comment: don't `button = Button().pack()` because `pack()` returns `None` and you get `None` in `button`

Comment: how would you change the text on the button and label?

Comment: use `command` without `lambda` - `command=self.loop` or add `()` in `loop`- `command=lambda: self.loop()`

Comment: thanks but when I do this, the label updates fine but the buttons just get added to the button. So I get the buttons for the previous one and the buttons for this one

Comment: You create new buttons in `loop` and add them - old buttons will not disapear if you don't remove them (`button.forget()` to only hide, `button.destroy()` to remove). So better create buttons once and later replace only text on buttons.

Answer (score 0):

First I create empty label and buttons and later I use `loop` to change only text on label and buttons.

I use list instead of dictionary and `self.current` to control which data from list I have to use as text.

```
import tkinter as tk

q_a = [
    ["label 1", [1,2,3,4]],
    ["label 2", [5,6,7,8]],
]    

class ExampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.label.pack()

        self.button1 = tk.Button(self, command=self.loop)
        self.button1.pack()

        self.button2 = tk.Button(self, command=self.loop)
        self.button2.pack()

        self.button3 = tk.Button(self, command=self.loop)
        self.button3.pack()

        self.button4 = tk.Button(self, command=self.loop)
        self.button4.pack()

        self.last = len(q_a)
        self.current = -1

        # set first text 
        # because `self.current = -1` then it use `self.current = 0`
        self.loop()

    def loop(self):

        # get next element from list
        self.current += 1

        if self.current == self.last:
            self.label.configure(text="The end")
            # hide buttons
            self.button1.forget()
            self.button2.forget()
            self.button3.forget()
            self.button4.forget()
        else:
            self.label['text'] = q_a[self.current][0]
            self.button1['text'] = q_a[self.current][1][0]
            self.button2['text'] = q_a[self.current][1][1]
            self.button3['text'] = q_a[self.current][1][2]
            self.button4['text'] = q_a[self.current][1][3]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = ExampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: eventually you could keep buttons as list `button[0], etc,` and use `for` loop to change text on all buttons or hide all buttons.

---

BTW: To make more readable you can use list with dictionares

```
q_a = [
    {"q": "label 1", "a": [1,2,3,4]},
    {"q": "label 2", "a": [5,6,7,8]},
]
```

and

```
    else:
        self.label['text'] = q_a[self.current]["q"]
        self.button1['text'] = q_a[self.current]["a"][0]
        self.button2['text'] = q_a[self.current]["a"][1]
        self.button3['text'] = q_a[self.current]["a"][2]
        self.button4['text'] = q_a[self.current]["a"][3]
```

or even

```
    else:
        row = q_a[self.current]

        self.label['text'] = row["q"]
        self.button1['text'] = row["a"][0]
        self.button2['text'] = row["a"][1]
        self.button3['text'] = row["a"][2]
        self.button4['text'] = row["a"][3]
```

Comment: Thanks so much Furas! God bless you!

Comment: @JohnCarterMitchel I add exammple with list of dictionaries.